# Java GUI Switching panels using Card Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

Ok I'm using Card Layout to switch panels from 1 panel to a 2nd panel & then to a 3rd panel. I have been looking online but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for. I want my panels to be in different classes and to switch back and forth using buttons to the different panels. I found a couple of sources for this but all the panels are added to a an original panel and then it switch's to different panels using the same buttons from the original panel.

(i.e) Panel 2 uses buttons from Panel 1 to switch to Panel 3 and Panel 3 uses buttons from Panel 1 to switch to Panel 4 and Panel 4 uses buttons from Panel 1 to switch back to Panel 2.

But the way it should be is panel 1 uses buttons from panel 1 to switch to panel 2, panel 2 uses buttons from panel 2 to switch to panel 3 and panel 3 should use buttons from panel 3 to switch to panel 1 which means there should be no need for a 4th panel.

My issue is I want to use different buttons to switch back and forth and not the same buttons as I intend to write extra code in each button for each panel. Because I basically want to create 3 panels so that once details are added to the register form and the user clicks register the details are added to the database and then it switch's to a login panel and closes the register panel.
The login panel then takes in a username and a password if they match an entry in the database and the user clicks login go to new panel and close login panel.

Now I have the registering and login stages done it's just switching from 1 panel to the next is the issue. Is there a way to use card layout so you switch to different panels using different buttons for each panel to do this or is there some other method used to do this.

I can append my code if needed. but its connected to a database so it won't compile without the database.

Comment: Plus it's worth mentioning I'm new to using Card Layouts because I usually used multiple frames and switched between each frame although I know its bad programming.

Comment: I basically want to do what splungebob asked in an earlier question in stack overflow somehow not necessarily with card layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840686/cardlayout-switch-between-jpanels-by-buttonclick

Comment: *"I can append my code if needed. but its connected to a database so it won't compile without the database."* 1) We don't want a code dump, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Replace the DB with some hard coded data.

Answer (score 0):

You definitly need a 4. panel witch contains the 3 panels and has the cardLayout.

To change the cards from cards you need to hand over an actionlistener with the method next(). I made a small not visual nice example to show what I mean ;-)

```
public class CardExample{

private class panel extends JPanel{

    private panel(ActionListener alNext, String text){
        JButton buttonNext = new JButton("next");
        buttonNext.addActionListener(alNext);

        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(text);

        this.add(textLabel);
        this.add(buttonNext);
    }
}

public CardExample(){}

public static void main(String[] args){

   CardExample ce = new Cardexample();
   ce.myGUI();
}

private void myGUI() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);

    CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(cardLayout);

    ActionListener al = e -> cardLayout.next(frame.getContentPane());

    frame.getContentPane().add(new panel(al, "Panel 1"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new panel(al, "Panel 2"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new panel(al, "Panel 3"));

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether the buttons are on the same panel or a different panel is irrelevant.

The button just executes a method from the layout manager. You can use:

1. next(...) - to go the next panel in the CardLayout, or
2. show(...) - to show a specific panel in the CardLayout.

If you don't have access to the panel using the CardLayout you can easily get this. In the ActionListener for your button you can do something like:

```
JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource();
JPanel buttonPanel = (JPanel)button.getParent();
JPanel cardPanel = (JPanel)buttonPanel.getParent();
CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)cardPanel.getLayout();
layout.next(cardPanel);
```